# Strange behavior: ternary operator for functions

Tags: python, function, ternary-operator

Here is a simplified example of my problem. I thought that these functions would have exactly the same behavior:

```
def f1(l):
    if type(l[0][0])==list: f=lambda x:x[0][0]
    else: f=lambda x:x[0]
    l.sort(key=f,reverse=True)

def f2(l):
    f=lambda x:x[0][0] if type(l[0][0])==list else lambda x:x[0]
    l.sort(key=f,reverse=True)

l=[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

But in reality `f1(l)` works fine when `f2(l)` collapses with the exception:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So the question is why is it so and is it possible to use ternary operator that returns one of the functions at all?

Comment: This is sort of tangential, but maybe this is one of those situations where a lambda makes things less easy to read rather than more. How about a `def getKey(x):` that examines `x` and returns `x[0]` or `x[0][0]` or whatever you need? Then `l.sort(key=getKey,reverse=True)`.

Comment: @Asad Yeah, that's a great point, although it may work a little slower than original version.

Comment: I'm not sure I see why it would be slower. It avoids the overhead of making a function every time you call `f1` or `f2`, so if anything it would be (insignificantly) more performant. I wouldn't say the difference is worth worrying about either way.

Comment: @Asad My comment was based on assumption that original approach makes decision only once per call and then uses one of `lambda`s as `key`, while `getkey` approach examines each element in the list and every time makes the same(redundant) decision. 

I made some tests. They show that original approach is approximately 2 times faster then `getkey` one. It doesn't matter much for my task, although. I vote for readability in this case.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. In that case, you can return the correct lambda from `getKey`, and have `l.sort(key=getKey(l),reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lambda` has the [lowest precedence among operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#operator-precedence). This is why Python parses that line as

```
f = lambda x: (x[0][0] if type(l[0][0]) == list else lambda x: x[0])
```

The fix is to wrap individual `lambda`s in parentheses:

```
f = (lambda x: x[0][0]) if type(l[0][0]) == list else (lambda x: x[0])
```

That said, `type(l[0][0]) == list` is kinda wrong, `isinstance(l[0][0], list)` would be the best way (it also handles subclasses of `list`).